# How can I calculate even intervals within a timestamp?

Tags: arithmetic

I know this is some simple thing, and I *used* to know it, but I just can't recall it.

I'm writing an application that takes screenshots of videos in a user's library. If a video is 35 minutes long, I want to take five screenshots, which are evenly spaced from each other and from the beginning and end.

My best guess so far is to say that `interval = length / (num_screenshots + 2)`, where `length` is the video's total length as a number of seconds. Then I take a screenshot at `0 + (interval * 1)`, `0 + (interval * 2)`, etc up to 5.

But is that the correct/simplest way to calculate this? It feels like there's some obvious thing I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

For **n** evenly spaced screenshots, there are **n + 1** total intervals, so the formula for each interval should be `interval = length / (num_screenshots + 1)`.  The first mark will be at `(interval * 1)`, the second at `(interval * 2)`, and ending in `(interval * n)`.  I don't see a much simpler way to due this, it seems quite simple to me.

[Interval Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Weft.png)